# What is a good way to generate a random 32 byte buffer in node js javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, buffer

I'm attempting to create a random 32 byte buffer, here's what I have (not working):

```
let buf = Buffer.alloc(32).fill(0)
console.log('Buffer: ',buf)
buf.writeUInt16BE(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2147483647).toString(16),5)
console.log('Random Buffer: ',buf)
```

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: [_"Behavior is undefined when `value` is anything other than an unsigned 16-bit integer"_](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writeuint16be_value_offset), you're passing a _string_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback):

```js
import { randomBytes } from 'crypto'
const buf = randomBytes(32)
console.log('Random Buffer: ', buf)
```

(If you have a CommonJS file and not a module, you need `const { randomBytes } = require('crypto')` instead of the first line.)

Comment: Thanks, I found I needed `let crypto = require('crypto')`

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`crypto.randomFill`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomfill_buffer_offset_size_callback) to fill the Buffer:

```js
crypto.randomFill(buf, (err, buf) => {
    console.log('Random Buffer: ', buf);
});
```